# What is the probability that the medicine has effect on him?

Tags: probability, random-variables

The number of times that an individual get sick with flu in one year it can be modeled as a random Poisson variable of
so on average the individual has 5 flues a year. A drug store
has developed a medicine that promises to reduce the number of annual flu in a way
that the Poisson distribution will have an average of 3, but medicine only has
effect on 75% of the population. For the other 25% of the population, the
Medicine has no effect.
If an individual tests the medicine for a year and during this period. What is the probability that the medicine has effect on him?

My try:

The Poisson distribution for 3 average flus in one year is: $$f_X(x)=\begin{cases}e^{-3}\frac{3^x}{x!} \qquad if \qquad x=1,2,... \\ 0 \qquad in\ other\ case \end{cases}$$
with $X$ is the number of flus in one year.

Then the probability of the medicine haveing effect on him is: $$P(X=2)*(\frac{3}{4})$$
$$=\frac{27}{8e^3}=0.16803...$$

I´m not sure of my results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having the flu $5$ times a year on average is not realistic, but let's just assume this is the case and look at the math.  That said, your question is incomplete.  You are missing something after the phrase

> If an individual tests the medicine for a year and during this period. [???]

Let's suppose that this sentence is supposed to read:

> If an individual tests the medicine for a year and during this period experiences $x$ illnesses, what is the probability that the medicine is effective for this individual?

Intuitively, if $x$ is "small," then we should hypothesize that the medicine is effective, and if $x$ is "large," we should hypothesize the opposite.  But how do we translate this intuition into probability?  Well, suppose $A$ is the event that the medicine is effective for this individual, and let $\bar A$ be the complementary event; i.e., the medicine does not work for this individual.  Next, let $X$ represent the random number of such illnesses experienced by this individual in one year.  We are given:
$$X \mid A \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda = 3), \quad \Pr[X = x \mid A] = e^{-3} \frac{3^x}{x!}, \\
X \mid \bar A \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda = 5), \quad \Pr[X = x \mid \bar A] = e^{-5} \frac{5^x}{x!}.$$  We are also given $$\Pr[A] = 0.75, \quad \Pr[\bar A] = 1 - 0.75 = 0.25.$$
We are asked to find $$\Pr[A \mid X = x],$$ that is to say, the probability that the medicine is effective given $x$ illnesses observed.  To this end, we apply Bayes' theorem:  $$\Pr[A \mid X = x] = \frac{\Pr[X = x \mid A]\Pr[A]}{\Pr[X = x]}.$$  The probabilities in the numerator are given, but the denominator, the *unconditional* or *marginal* distribution of the number of illnesses, is not.  To obtain this, we use the law of total probability, conditioning on $A$:  $$\Pr[X = x] = \Pr[X = x \mid A]\Pr[A] + \Pr[X = x \mid \bar A]\Pr[\bar A].$$  Now we simply substitute everything we have been given and the rest is computation, which I have left as an exercise for the reader.  Is the resulting answer consistent with our earlier intuition; that is to say, is $\Pr[A \mid X = x]$ a decreasing function of $x$?